# Symfony 2 - multi db - deploy

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, doctrine-orm

In my CMS there is a possibility to create versions of your product (site). After product is ready it should be deployed to another db, but only this one final version of the product.

So my question is how to do it?

Edit: What I need to achive is to get one of the products and all its referances from one DB(this db contains stages, versions of making the product) and paste it to another that have exacly the same structure but is going to contain only final versions of products (completed only).

I thought that If I could have two entity managers with diffrent configuration mapped for all entities it could work. But unfotunatly it is not possible, i can have only once set auto_mapping with true for one of my EM in config.yml http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Comment: Welcome to all of you aswell:)

Comment: The reference manual: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#custom-mapping-entities-in-a-bundle shows how you can list bundles instead of using auto mapping.  It's worth taking the time to understand how the doctrine configuration works.